# In C++, what is the correct way to do perfect forwarding an lvalue to a function template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, perfect-forwarding

What is the correct way to accept a parameter pack for perfect-forwarding, such that it will take any type and simply forward them? The following code works on regular types but fails on pointer types:

```
template<typename ...A>
void b(A &&... args)
{}

template<typename ...A>
void a(A &&... args)
{
    b(std::forward<A>(args)...);
}


int main() {

    // ok
    a<int>(5);

    // error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int*&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int*’
    int *foo = nullptr;
    a<int*>(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

[edit] Thanks for the quick and great replies! I oversimplified - this is a closer example of the problem I am trying to solve:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename F>
struct fun;

template<typename F, typename ...A>
struct fun<F(A...)>
{
    void b(A &&... args)
    {}
    
    void a(A &&... args)
    {
        b(std::forward<A>(args)...);
    }
};

int main() {

    // ok
    fun<void(int)> f1;
    f1.a(5);

    // error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'
    fun<void(int)> f2;
    int x = 5;
    f2.a(x);

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, I don't have the luxury to let the template adjust automatically... Any idea how this can be achieved?

[edit 2] as pointed out in the comments, this has nothing to do with pointers, I updated my sample to simply use an `lvalue`

Comment: That's not a fair comparison though. A fairer one would be `int bar = 5; a<int>(bar)` - same error, not about pointers.

Comment: You're right, I did not realize this was about `lvalue` and had nothing to do with pointers, even in my new example it does not have to be a pointer. Thanks for highlighting this!

Comment: Now, `fun::a` accepts only rvalue arguments. Also, it's not a function template, therefore, the perfect forwarding will not work. If you want to forward its arguments, write something as `template<Ts...> void a(Ts&&... args) { b(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); };`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not specify template arguments explicitly; which just prevents template argument deduction from working with [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), and yields unexpected result.

```
a<int>(5);    // A is specified as int then function parameter's type is int&&.
              // 5 is an rvalue and could be bound to int&&

a<int*>(foo); // A is specified as int* then function parameter's type is int* &&.
              // foo is an lvalue and couldn't be bound to int* &&
```

Just

```
a(5);   // 5 is rvalue, then A is deduced as int and function parameter's type collapses to int&&

int *foo = nullptr;
a(foo); // foo is lvalue, then A is deduced as int* & and function parameter's type collapses to int* &
```

**EDIT**

Firstly both the member functions `b` and `a` are not template, and their parameters are not declared as [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) at all.

The code doesn't work because

```
fun<void(int)> f2;
int x = 5;
f2.a(x); // A is specified as int then function parameter's type is int &&.
         // x is an lvalue and couldn't be bound to int &&
```

I'm not sure about your intent, you can change it to

```
fun<void(int&)> f2;
//          ^
int x = 5;
f2.a(x); // A is specified as int& then function parameter's type collapses to int&.
         // x is an lvalue and could be bound to int&
```

Or make them function templates and still apply forwarding reference.

```
template <typename... T>
void b(T &&... args)
{}

template <typename... T>
void a(T &&... args)
{
    b(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively (if you insist on explicit template argument), you can write `a<int*&>(foo);`.

Comment: ah you are absolutely right... but let me update my question, my actual problem is a bit more complex and I oversimplified :(

Comment: @GaspardP Answer revised.

Comment: Thanks! making the member function templates on a different type allows the types to be forwarded smoothly.